# Generate dictionary from a pandas dataframe with multiple columns combined as the keys, remaining columns as values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a dictionary from a pandas dataframe. Specifically, I need to:

1. Take the first (x) columns and use the data points in each of their rows, together, as keys.
2. Compile a dictionary for each key using the remaining data points in the row as values, as a list.

Let's use this sample dataframe for the sake of simplicity.

1. Generate dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'c1':a1, 'c2':110, 'c3':'xyz', 'c4':24}, 
    {'c1':b2,'c2':100, 'c3':'jdf', 'c4':15}, 
    {'c1':a1,'c2':110, 'c3':'kjl', 'c4':125},
    {'c1':b2, 'c2':100, 'c3':'abc', 'c4':71},
])

    c1  c2  c3  c4
0   a1  110 xyz 24
1   b2  100 jdf 15
2   a1  110 kjl 125
3   b2  100 abc 71
```

2. Yield the following:

```
new_dict = some code

new_dict

{('a1', 110): [['xyz', 24], ['kjl', 125]], ('b2', 100): [['jdf', 15], ['abc', 71]]}
```

I've tried many, many things, including creating a list of tuple lists for the keys, assigning unique lists as keys to a new dictionary (with values empty lists)--but I can't then populate the values.

I'm able to compile a dictionary with a single column as the key, and everything else as needed, like this:

```
test_dict = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['c1'] in test_dict:
        test_dict[row['c1']].append([row['c2'], row['c3'], row['c4']])
    else:
        test_dict[row['c1']] = []
        test_dict[row['c1']].append([row['c2'], row['c3'], row['c4']])
```

But I can't make the jump to combining multiple columns as the key.

Comment: Thanks @Accumulation for pointing out the discrepancy in my sample data. I have edited the example. Your solution worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'c1': 'a1', 'c2': 110, 'c3': 'xyz', 'c4': 24},
    {'c1': 'b2', 'c2': 100, 'c3': 'jdf', 'c4': 15},
    {'c1': 'a1', 'c2': 110, 'c3': 'kjl', 'c4': 125},
    {'c1': 'b2', 'c2': 100, 'c3': 'abc', 'c4': 71},
])
```

You could [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), aggregate and then convert to dictionary ([to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)):

```
groups = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).apply(lambda x: x[['c3', 'c4']].values.tolist()).to_dict()
print(groups)
```

**Output**

```
{('a1', 110): [['xyz', 24], ['kjl', 125]], ('b2', 100): [['jdf', 15], ['abc', 71]]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution doesn't quite return what I was looking for. The keys were correct, but the values were not what I specified. This was insightful though.

Comment: @WartimeHotTot Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
test_dict = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['c1'], row['c2']) in test_dict:
        test_dict[(row['c1'], row['c2'])].append([row['c3'], row['c4']])
    else:
        test_dict[(row['c1'], row['c2'])] = [[row['c3'], row['c4']]]

test_dict

{('a1', 100): [['xyz', 24], ['kjl', 125]], ('b2', 110): [['jdf', 15], ['abc', 71]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `groupby`:

```
(df.groupby(['c1','c2'])
   .apply(lambda x: x[['c3','c4']].values)
   .to_dict()
)
```

Output:

```
{('a1', 110): array([['xyz', 24],
        ['kjl', 125]], dtype=object), ('b2', 100): array([['jdf', 15],
        ['abc', 71]], dtype=object)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you used to create the dataframe doesn't match the dataframe that you present as an example, but what you seem to be wanting can be done with:

```
x = 2
key_cols =  list(df.columns[:x])
value_cols = df.columns[x:]
new_dict = df.groupby(key_cols).apply(lambda sub_df: sub_df[value_cols].values.tolist()).to_dict()
```